# How do I plot different parts of a same function?

Tags: plotting, complex

Let's say that I got a complex function $f$ of a real variable $x$, i.e. $f(x)$. Suppose that I want to plot the real part of $f$, i.e. $\Re(f(x))$.

My question is: should I enclose `Re[f[x]]` in the command `ComplexExpand`? Or does `Re[f[x]]` already give the real part of $f$?

Comment: Try and find out :)  sometimes you need to do ComplexExpand to tell Mathematica to assume variables are real in the expression. It depends on the expression. Why not try both cases and see what you get? you need to do Re(expression) to plot the real part of whatever you end up with. _while my question concerns a simple case._ may be you could post such an example?

Comment: That's because Mathematica will take forever to plot the function when I use ComplexExpand. When I enclose $f$ in Re[ ] only, it takes just a few minutes!

Comment: As I said, it depends on the expression. If you do not do ComplexExpand, you could end with lots of `Conjugate` and `Re` terms as a result because Mathematica does not know if a symbol is real  (default is complex).

Comment: oh I see. Is there a way to tell Mathematica my variable $x$ is real? It is the only variable in the problem, by the way.

Comment: _. Is there a way to tell Mathematica my variable x is real?_ that what `ComplexExpand` does. But you can always apply your own assumptions. I.e. try `Assuming[Element[x,Reals],Re[expression]]` But if you post an example, it will easier/.

Comment: If `ComplexExpand` takes forever inside the Plot , may be you are doing something wrong. If you post such an example which takes long time. May be you need to use `Evaluate` on it. Hard to know. There can be 100 reasons why.

Comment: Hi Nasser. The function I'm considering is an infinite series* whose terms are not analytical. So I'm not sure it would be of help posting it here. Do you still want to see it?
*I want to plot only the first few terms of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the same values and plots with `Re[f[x]]`, `ComplexExpand[Re[f[x]]]`, or `Re[ComplexExpand[f[x]]]`, with or without `Evaluate`. However, the timing varies:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := Cos[I^x] Sin[I^x]

Plot[Evaluate@Re@f@x, {x, -5, 5}] // RepeatedTiming
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@ComplexExpand@Re@f@x, {x, -5, 5}] // RepeatedTiming
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@Re@ComplexExpand@f@x, {x, -5, 5}] // RepeatedTiming
```

[image]

```
Plot[Re@f@x, {x, -5, 5}] // RepeatedTiming
```

[image]

```
Plot[ComplexExpand@Re@f@x, {x, -5, 5}] // RepeatedTiming
```

[image]

```
Plot[Re@ComplexExpand@f@x, {x, -5, 5}] // RepeatedTiming
```

[image]

Your mileage may vary...

Comment: Hi Bob. So in what situation would one need to use `Re` inside `ComplexExpand`? From what you say, I suppose that we don't need the latter command at all when it comes to plotting.

Comment: `ComplexExpand` will assume that all variables are real unless told otherwise; however, for a complex function, the result from using `ComplexExpand` will still be complex. To plot the function you must still take the `Re` or `Im` part, either before or after `ComplexExpand`. The reason for using `ComplexExpand` is to avoid complex artifacts from numeric evaluation of `Re[f[x]]` or `Im[f[x]]`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "complex artifacts"?

Comment: Some real expressions contain complex components such that the imaginary parts cancel to give the real result. However, numerical results may not exactly cancel the imaginary parts and result in small imaginary components, I.e., artifacts of the lack of infinite precision. This is more likely to occur with machine precision calculations since they do not track nor attempt to control precision.

Comment: I got it. Unfortunately, I think I can't upvote your answer. Nevertheless, thank you very much.

Comment: @dekees you can accept Bob's answer, though, if you found it useful. Just click on the checkmark next to it. Nicely done Bob!